Why are we taught that hot air rises?
So I'm not an English major or anything near. However, I have read quite a lot in my time. I have a decent vocabulary.
So here is my issue...
When I was young it was widely taught that hot air rises. And in the English language it would seem that we say a thing that's doing the action is the subject or whatever.... Or I don't know if that's correct but the thing doing the action like "the plane is flying" here we have the object or subject of plane and it is doing an action flying I can get on board with that because it's expending a large amount of energy to stay in the air.
However hot air is not acting in any sense of the word it is being acted upon so why do we say that the hot air rises? When in fact it is buoyed or forced upward by the denser colder air?
Or why do we say things fall to the Earth? I'm holding something in my hand in a closed fist with my palm facing downward and I open my hand what happens to that object? Does it actually fall is there some action it is taking to make itself fall?. No. It is pulled to the Earth...
I was surprised to find kids are still taught that to this day when in fact that is not what's going on Hot Air does not rise and objects do not fall.
While we have come to agree upon the definitions of the words rising and falling and that they apply to what we are talking about in the sense that objects are acted upon or actually do an action it is incorrect to think this way about hot air rising and things falling without being acted upon. Such a fundamental error, ascribing an ability or action to something that does not have it or is not capable of,  in thinking obviously precludes one from understanding more complex fundamental phenomenon.
So there's my issue and my question is why is it being taught in school that hot air rises and objects fall?

That's more a question for linguistics than philosophy. Language has many quirks. But this just seems to be a common way of expressing necessary state changes without implying agency or origin of energy.

Yes. English is ambiguous as to verb-agency. Other languages are more clear. See 3 levels of (in)direction in Hindi "to do"

Note also we say planes fly. We dont say submarines swim. Why the partiality? Before 1903 it was straightforward: The natural swimmers were fish, the natural fly-rs were birds

"However hot air is not acting" - doesn't matter, is it going up? Then it's rising. I think the problem is you're reading way too much into a basic phrase.

As often happens an interesting question is about to be closed. But you may find it of substance to try asking chapGPT (or equivalent) the following: "languages that change the verb to indicate agency"

I don't see why it is a problem. Sometimes you just want to say that something happens (or happened) without commitment to whether there was any agency involved. The glass shattered. The patient died. The ice melted. The battery ran out. I daresay other languages distinguish verbs differently, and some languages have more than two voices, but the usage does not seem misleading to me.

the question makes no sense to me at all. hot air does indeed rise. if you used an oven or been to the sauna i'm sure you would know that

You would end up not having any verbs for most things that happened, or have to express them in a convoluted and pedantic way. Instead of turning the light on, you would be completing an electric circuit that caused current to flow in a semiconductor junction which emitted large numbers of ultraviolet photons that were immediately absorbed by a phosphor coating that reradiated them as visible light. Now, your turn: describe seeing the light come on. That said (whew!) I have sympathy for your question because I used to 'wonder' it myself.
